# virt-manager - ImportError: No module named gi

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

When I run **virt-manager --no-fork** on macOS 10.13 High Sierra I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/virt-manager/1.5.0/libexec/share/virt-manager/virt-manager", line 31, in <module>
    import gi
ImportError: No module named gi
```

python version 2.7.6 on macOS

Tried mulitple solutions (by googling) none fixed the issue, any ideas how to solve "ImportError: No module named gi" error?

Answer (score 0):

On debian 9.7 I had the same problem, I fixed:

```sh
apt install python-gobject-2-dev python-gobject-dev libvirt-glib-1.0-dev python3-libxml2 libosinfo-1.0-dev
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO ! :) .It would be nice and helpful if you can please use the correct image description instead of just saying "enter image description here". Thanks

Answer (score -1):

(Arch-linux) I have anaconda installed which breaks virt-manager. But there is no need to uninstall it, just renamed anaconda folder to anything else and virt-manager works again. When need to use anaconda, undo the folder name change. Anaconda modifies PATH environment and when the folder is not present (the trick to rename it) system will look to a standard location. I think the problem could be related.

Comment: Hi, the user is running macOS and not ArchLinux. Also, it sounds like a python package is missing and not a conflict with another installed package.